# FFMPEG audio not lining up

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, opentok

I am using OpenTok to build a live video platform. It generates webm files from each users stream.

I am using FFMPEG to convert webm (WEBRTC) videos to MP4s to edit in my NLE. The problem I am having is my audio is drifting. I THINK it is because the user pauses the audio during the stream. This is the command i'm running

```
ffmpeg -acodec libopus -i 65520df3-1033-480e-adde-1856d18e2352.webm  -max_muxing_queue_size 99999999 65520df3-1033-480e-adde-1856d18e2352.webm.new.mp4
```

The problem is I think, whenever the user muted themselves, there are no frames. But the PTS is in tact.

This is from the OpenTok documentation (my WebRTC platform)

> Audio and video frames may not arrive with monotonic timestamps; frame rates are not always consistent. This is especially relevant if either the video or audio track is disabled for a time, using one of publishVideo or publishAudio publisher properties.

> Frame presentation timestamps (PTS) are written based on NTP
> timestamps taken at the time of capture, offset by the timestamp of
> the first received frame. Even if a track is muted and later unmuted,
> the timestamp offset should remain consistent throughout the duration
> of the entire stream. When decoding in post-processing, a gap in PTS
> between consecutive frames will exist for the duration of the track
> mute: there are no "silent" frames in the container.

How can I convert these files and have them play in sync? Note, when I play in QuickTime or VLC, the files are synced correctly.

**EDIT**
I've gotten pretty close with this command:

```
 ffmpeg -acodec libopus -i $f -max_muxing_queue_size 99999999 -vsync 1 -af aresample=async=1 -r 30 $f.mp4
```

But every once in a while, I get a video where the audio starts right away, and they wont actually be talking in the video until half-way thought the video. My guess is they muted themselves during the video conference... so in some cases audio is 5-10 mins ahead. Again, plays fine in quicktime, but pulled into my NLE, its way off.

Comment: There they use `-vsync 0` and talk about retaining PTS, didn't get it fully though, https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25189/how-to-decode-the-pts-timestamps-and-extract-the-video-frames